# libgdx: Dispose Screen on Demand

Tags: libgdx, screen

Say I have a splash screen. This screen is loaded only at the beginning of the game, and afterwards I don't use it.
Is it possible to dispose this screen on demand?

I tried to dispose it right after setting the screen after the splash, and also tried to call `dispose()` on the `hide()` method.
Both of the tries rendered in an exception.

How can I dispose this screen on demand? I have there pretty heavy textures, and wanted to free the memory as soon as possible.

Example:

```
// SplashScreen class
class SplashScreen implements Screen {
    private boolean renderingEnabled = true;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (!renderingEnabled) {
                return;
            }

            spriteBatch.begin();
            // here render the animations
            spriteBatch.end();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            renderingEnabled = false;

            // here come the disposing of SpriteBatch and TextureAtlas
            atlas.dispose();
            atlas = null;

            spriteBatch.dispose();
            spriteBatch = null;
        }
    }
}


// The usage
game.setScreen(splashScreen);
...
// now when the splash screen animation is finished, I am calling the following from the controller:
splashScreen.dispose();
game.setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
```

I get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 398
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mypackage.SplashScreen.render(SplashScreen.java:85)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at mypackage.Game.render(MyGame.java:33)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:414)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

And when I have the following dispose pattern (disposing after showing the `mainMenuScreen`)

```
// The usage
game.setScreen(splashScreen);
...
// now when the splash screen animation is finished, I am calling the following from the controller:
game.setScreen(mainMenuScreen);
splashScreen.dispose();
```

I get the same exception.
The exception is on `spriteBatch.end()` row inside the render method. The `spriteBatch` member turns to be null. Really confusing, since I have mutual exclusive lock on the `render` and the `dispose` methods.

Comment: Show some code. What exception do you get?

Comment: added the code and the exception

Comment: Are you trying to do this multi-threaded? What class and method are you calling `splashScreen.dispose()` from?

Comment: I am not, unless libgdx does it multi-threaded. I have a splash screen which has a controller which controles the animations on the screen. Once all the animations are finished I call from the controller the setScreen(mainMenuScreen) and dispose the splash screen or vice versa. Both scenarios render the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out, is that LibGDX works in one thread.
What happens is the following. When the `game.setScreen(mainMenuScreen)` is called, and the program is in the middle of the `render` method of the splash screen, the thread is interrupted, and the code for setting the *mainMenuScreen* is executed (in the `Game` class), and then going back to continue the render method of the splash screen. Weird, right? After setting the new screen still to render the old screen?

Anyways, what I did is the following:
As part of the `Game.setScreen(Screen screen)` method, the `Screen.hide()` method is called on the old screen.
So what I did, I introduced a flag, `hideCalled` and set it to *true* in the `hide()` event inside the splash screen.
Inside the `render` method of the splash screen I check this flag at the beginning and at the end of the method. If the flag is *true* - I dispose the screen.

Comment: I just implemented this, and while it did stop an exception from being thrown it also seems that the `dispose()` method is never being called, since my log statements never execute. Why? No idea. Can you verify that your dispose method is definitely being called?

Comment: The dispose() method of a screen is never called automaticly. You will have to call it manually if you wanna use it. That's probably the reason why it isn't showing up in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking about AssetManager, maybe it would help you with this problem in a cleaner way.
Take a look [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets).
I see it loads assets asynchronously so maybe this problem that you described would not be happening again.

And just for some knowledge sharing, I changed screens with another approach:
I used actions attached to an image, and these actions are executed in the order they are added. First i created an action which loads the images, then, when this first action was finished, i added another action which switches the screen.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void show() {
        stage.addActor(splashImage);

        splashImage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.alpha(0), Actions.run(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Assets.load();
            }
        }), Actions.fadeIn(0.5f), Actions.delay(1), Actions.fadeOut(0.5f), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Utils.changeGameScreen(new GameScreen());
                // ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new
                // GameScreen());
            }
        })));

    }
```